# Наличие или отсутствие запятой в причастном обороте с уточнением

Tags: запятые, причастный-оборот

Какой вариант является правильным? Наличие или отсутствие запятой перед "для".

1. > 3 сообщения, отмеченных тревогой, для привлечения внимания модераторов
2. > 3 сообщения, отмеченных тревогой для привлечения внимания модераторов